# Strange behaviour using cut and sed on bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a plain text file organized in 2 columns. I want to cut each column and createa a new line with it, then I want to add at the end of each line the string "_mystring".

**Example**

A file with the content:

```
myline1 myline11 
myline2 myline22
```

This will produce 2 files.

*file 1:*

```
myline1_mystring
myline2_mystring
```

*file 2:*

```
myline11_mystring
myline22_mystring
```

---

To get that I execute this simple script:

```
cat mytext.txt | cut -f $1 |sed "s/$/_mystring/" > file"$1"
```

So I can execute that using the argument(`$1`) to select the column. It works for the first column, It's replacing the `$1` with `1`. But when it cames to the second column it fails and it creates the file like this:

```
_mystringline1
_mystringline2
```

I think that can be related to something happening with the `cut` and `sed` command since I tried another `sed` options to achieve adding the string at the end and I always get the same result, but I don't know how to fix it.

**Edit**
Here I show the content of the real file:

```
account@for     justificar
account@for@    explicar
account@for     dar@cuentas@de
act@as  servir@de
act@as  hacer@de
act@for representar@a
act@on  reaccionar@a
act@on  actuar@sobre
act@on  responder@a
act@out representar
```

Here you have the result of `xxd mytext.txt`:

```
00000000: 6163 636f 756e 7440 666f 7209 6a75 7374  account@for.just
00000010: 6966 6963 6172 0d0a 6163 636f 756e 7440  ificar..account@
00000020: 666f 7240 0965 7870 6c69 6361 720d 0a61  for@.explicar..a
00000030: 6363 6f75 6e74 4066 6f72 0964 6172 4063  ccount@for.dar@c
00000040: 7565 6e74 6173 4064 650d 0a61 6374 4061  uentas@de..act@a
00000050: 7309 7365 7276 6972 4064 650d 0a61 6374  s.servir@de..act
00000060: 4061 7309 6861 6365 7240 6465 0d0a 6163  @as.hacer@de..ac
00000070: 7440 666f 7209 7265 7072 6573 656e 7461  t@for.representa
00000080: 7240 610d 0a61 6374 406f 6e09 7265 6163  r@a..act@on.reac
00000090: 6369 6f6e 6172 4061 0d0a 6163 7440 6f6e  cionar@a..act@on
000000a0: 0961 6374 7561 7240 736f 6272 650d 0a61  .actuar@sobre..a
000000b0: 6374 406f 6e09 7265 7370 6f6e 6465 7240  ct@on.responder@
000000c0: 610d 0a61 6374 406f 7574 0972 6570 7265  a..act@out.repre
000000d0: 7365 6e74 6172 0d0a                      sentar..
```

and this is the result of `hexdump -c mytext.txt`:

```
0000000   a   c   c   o   u   n   t   @   f   o   r  \t   j   u   s   t
0000010   i   f   i   c   a   r  \r  \n   a   c   c   o   u   n   t   @
0000020   f   o   r   @  \t   e   x   p   l   i   c   a   r  \r  \n   a
0000030   c   c   o   u   n   t   @   f   o   r  \t   d   a   r   @   c
0000040   u   e   n   t   a   s   @   d   e  \r  \n   a   c   t   @   a
0000050   s  \t   s   e   r   v   i   r   @   d   e  \r  \n   a   c   t
0000060   @   a   s  \t   h   a   c   e   r   @   d   e  \r  \n   a   c
0000070   t   @   f   o   r  \t   r   e   p   r   e   s   e   n   t   a
0000080   r   @   a  \r  \n   a   c   t   @   o   n  \t   r   e   a   c
0000090   c   i   o   n   a   r   @   a  \r  \n   a   c   t   @   o   n
00000a0  \t   a   c   t   u   a   r   @   s   o   b   r   e  \r  \n   a
00000b0   c   t   @   o   n  \t   r   e   s   p   o   n   d   e   r   @
00000c0   a  \r  \n   a   c   t   @   o   u   t  \t   r   e   p   r   e
00000d0   s   e   n   t   a   r  \r  \n                                
00000d8
```

Comment: You have missed setting the de-limiter for `cut`, refer my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NeronLeVelu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43474407/5291015) shows a nice way to do this in `Awk`, but the *real* problem with your solution is you are not passing the de-limiter to use for `cut`, which you need to give with the `-d` switch. Passing a single whitespace to it and avoiding [usless-use-of-cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) as

```
cut -d' ' -f "$1" mytext.txt | sed "s/$/_VERB/" > file"$1"
```

should solve your problem.

---

Your comments below indicate your de-limiter is a <kbd>tab</kbd>, which you can specify now as

```
cut -d$'\t' -f "$1" mytext.txt | sed "s/$/_VERB/" > file"$1"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This doesn't solve the problem. If I execute the cut command I get the column that I want without trouble (the delimiter is '\t' in the real example). Anyways I tried this adding de delimiter param but it hasn't helped.

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres: Can you explain what is not working? When run from the command line its working but not in script?

Comment: If I run `cut -f 2` I can see the that the output corresponds to the desired column. When I execute it piped with sed `cut -d' ' -f 2 mytext.txt | sed "s/$/_VERB/"` I get the error. "mystring" is not being concat at the end of the line

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres: Refer my update, that's how you use the tab as the de-limiter

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres: I do hope you are aware, that the `sed` command you are trying appends the string `_VERB` at last, since `$` matches the end, if you are looking for `mystring`, do `cut -d$'\t' -f 2 mytext.txt | sed "s/$/_mystring/"`

Comment: yes. I make a mess with the copy paste. I want the string "mystring" and I was using it properly. Thanks for spotting the error on the question.

Comment: Done ;) Thank you

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres: So what is not working now? It is supposed to work with the tab de-limiter

Comment: No, the error was those "\r" that are present on the hexdump. I just replace them with sed and everything is working now

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres: Happy to be of help!

Answer (score 4):

better with awk (if available in your constraint)

```
awk '{print $1 "_mystring" > "file1";print $2 "_mystring" > "file2"}' mytext.txt
```

more generic:

```
awk -v MyStr="_mystring" '{for(i=0;i<=NF;i++) print $i MyStr > "file" i }' mytext.txt
```

now a pure sed version:

```
sed -e 's/^ *//;s/ *$/_mystring/;h;s/ .*/_mystring/;w file1' -e 'x;s/.* //;w file2' -e 'd' mytext.txt
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I'd prefer continue using sed. But still a nice one, so here it's my upvote

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres added a pure sed version to avoid piping process and loop for files separation

Answer (score 1):

If I define:

```
myscript() { cut -f$1 | sed 's/$/_VERB/' > file$1; }
```

And run:

```
cat file | myscript 1
cat file | myscript 2
head file1 file2
```

I get:

```
==> file1 <==
myline1_VERB
myline2_VERB

==> file2 <==
myline11_VERB
myline22_VERB
```

Comment: I tried copypasting your code. file 1 is generated properly but not file2.

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres: Please add the output of either `xxd file` or `od -xa file` to your question

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres: Where `file` is the  input file you are using, btw.

Comment: the info was added to the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to the end of line character `\r`. I remove them using `sed "s/\\r//g"` and then everything started to work as expected.